# automatic pure javascript slideshow. It's working on onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to the automatic slideshow. I did it with onclick event.

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<img class="mySlides" src="assets/img/local/s2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="assets/img/local/s3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="assets/img/local/s4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="assets/img/local/s1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="assets/img/local/s5.jpg" style="width:100%">
```

The problem is when I click on **Next** and **Previous** button with onclick function call then slideshow is working. But I want also it ***automatic***.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: use `setInterval` (repeats) or `setTimeout` (once, you call it again at the end of plusDivs):  `setInterval(showDivs, 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use setInterval and make use of your plusDivs function

```
setInterval(() => plusDivs(1), 5000); // for changing slide every 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your next click function inside a setIntervel()..so that it will call after every duration you mention

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    //your code goes here
}, 3000);
```

you can clear the interval at any point by calling

```
 clearInterval(interval);
```

Here is a Ref code which i had done..here automatic slide show will be there.. on touch of image it stop the slide show..on touchleave it will start again..on clicking the image it will take you to next image.
Ref:https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/POBvRz

Thanks !

Answer (score -2):

Here is how to call a function repeatedly (3000 - interval in milliseconds):

setInterval(function(){ plusDivs(n); }, 3000);